# 3 button state - normal, rollover (on hover), active (on click) with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, button, rollover, background-position

I'm using the following code to get my buttons to change to their rollover state when hovered over.

```
$('.button').hover(function(){
$(this).css('background-position', '0 -23px');
}, function(){
$(this).css('background-position', '0 0px');
});
```

with the .button class applied to all the button divs, using the background-position function where all the background images have all three states in the same image - at '0 0px' show the normal state, at '0 -23px' shows the rollover state, and at '0 -46px' shows the active state.

I'm trying to figure out how to get my buttons to show their active states when they are clicked, while having all other .button buttons go back to their normal states.  I've tried the following code which changes the buttons to their active states, but when the mouse is moved off the buttons they go back to their normal states.

```
$('.button').click(function(){
$(this).css('background-position', '0 -46px');
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you make a fiddle ?

Comment: So when you click it you want to stay in the "active" state?

Comment: why sont you create 3 classes in css (.hover, .rollover, .active) and just change class in jquery.. use .live.. I can show you the code if you tell how ur buttons are implemented...

Comment: I made a fiddle in case anyone is having a similar issue and wants to see how I implemented these solutions to get my buttons to work as I wanted --> http://jsfiddle.net/PPbFJ/11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add Class for this, like:

Add thi in your **CSS**

```
.active{background-position:0 -46px !important;}
```

And in **Jquery** use it like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

Read Docs http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you SO much!  Solved my issues and this is really helpful.  Love this site.

Comment: I made a fiddle in case anyone is having a similar issue and wants to see how I implemented these solutions to get my buttons to work as I wanted --> http://jsfiddle.net/PPbFJ/11/

Answer (score 12):

The best thing to do would be simple css implementation.

```
.button
{
    //your css
}
.button:active
{
    //your css
}
.button:hover
{
    //your css
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: The three button classes I implemented with Rohan Kumar's answer and it worked great.

Comment: I set up buttons in this way, but ran into a snag adding click events in Safari: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48106286/safari-click-event-and-active-state-cannot-coexist

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pseudo class a:active {background-img: - ;background-position: 0 -46px;}

Answer (score 0):

Now if you used to callback function in jquery than used to this formate ..

```
$('.button').hover(function(){
  $(this).css('background-position', '0 -23px', function(){
    $(this).css('background-position', '0 0');
  });
});
```

More about **[Call Back Function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/)**